# ReactiveUI ReactiveList and DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using [ReactiveUI](http://reactiveui.net/) [ReactiveLists](https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/lists/), in my projects, one of this ReactiveLists is   binded to `ItemsSource` `DependencyProperty` in my custom WPF MultiSelectComboBox:

```
<CustomControls:MultiSelectComboBox x:Name="CountriesCombobox" 
                        Width="200"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Repository.Countries}"
                        SelectedItems="{Binding Repository.SearchViewSelectedCountries, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

...

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable<object>), typeof(MultiSelectComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
    new PropertyChangedCallback(MultiSelectComboBox.OnItemsSourceChanged)));

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IEnumerable<object>), typeof(MultiSelectComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
 new PropertyChangedCallback(MultiSelectComboBox.OnSelectedItemsChanged)));

public IEnumerable<object> SelectedItems
{
    get { return (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
}

public IEnumerable<object> ItemsSource
{
    get { return (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

And after selecting one option in my ComboBox `SetSelectedItems` method is called:

```
private void SetSelectedItems()
{
    if (SelectedItems == null)
        SelectedItems = new List<object>();

    foreach (Node node in _nodeList)
    {
        if (node.IsSelected && node.Title != "All")
        {
            if (this.ItemsSource.Count() > 0)
            {
                var temp = SelectedItems.ToList();
                temp.Add(this.ItemsSource.First(x => x.ToString() == node.Title));
                SelectedItems = SelectedItems.Concat(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm trying to add `SelectedItems` to `SelectedItemsProperty`, the problem I have is that if my `ItemsSourceProperty` have differ type than `IEnumerable` binding didn't work and property is empty (I have tried types: `List`, `IList`, `ICollection`, `ReactiveList`, `IReactiveList`) and if it is as `IEnumerable`     `System.InvalidCastException` is thrown when I'm trying to cast `SelectedItems` to list:

```
var temp1 = (List<object>)SelectedItems;
```

And if I will try to use [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) method like sample above, `SelectedItems` is set to `null`. So my question is how can I add alements to `SelectedItems` when it is binded to `ReactiveList`?

It was created accordig to [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563862/Multi-Select-ComboBox-in-WPF) article.

Comment: Try making SelectedItems an ObservableCollection. BTW I don't think holding a collection of object types is good practice.

Comment: After changing to ObservableCollection my list is empty, somehow binding didn't work

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm missing something, but where is the ReactiveList here? Also, in the example you copied, the SelectedItems property is defined as Dictionary (stating that List can be used), why did you change it to IEnumerable?

Comment: Well ReactiveList is in my Repository class (Repository.Countries) that is  in my ViewModel and binded in xaml (first code), and i have changed to IEnumerable beacause it only works with ReactiveList.
public IReactiveList<ICountry> Countries { get; private set; }

Comment: What's the type of your source properties? You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Your issue is not reproducible based on the (lack of) details you have provided.

Comment: I think your Concat method on an Enumerable is bound to be problematic. Try `SelectedItems = temp;` in stead of `SelectedItems = SelectedItems.Concat(temp);`

Comment: After that SelectedItems is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it worked after I used [IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx) interface:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IList), typeof(MultiSelectComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
    new PropertyChangedCallback(MultiSelectComboBox.OnItemsSourceChanged)));

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IList), typeof(MultiSelectComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
    new PropertyChangedCallback(MultiSelectComboBox.OnSelectedItemsChanged)));

public IList ItemsSource
{
    get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}

public IList SelectedItems
{
    get { return (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
}
```

And then:

```
private void SetSelectedItems()
{
    SelectedItems.Clear();

    foreach (Node node in _nodeList)
    {
        if (node.IsSelected && node.Title != "All")
        {
            if (this.ItemsSource.Count > 0)
                SelectedItems.Add(this.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().ToList().First(x => x.ToString() == node.Title));
        }
    }
}
```